# I'm getting an error while running main.js. " Cannot find module 'app' ". Could anyone help me out

Tags: javascript, node.js

index.html

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

main.js

```
'use strict';

var app = require('app');
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');

var mainWindow = null;

app.on('ready', function() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        height: 600,
        width: 800
    });

    mainWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/app/index.html');
});
```

Comment: Can you try `require('electron').app;` instead of `require('app');`?

Comment: @CliffBurton Now it says cannot find module 'browser-window'

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot about it, write `require('electron').BrowserWindow;` instead of `require('browser-window');` too

Comment: @CliffBurton It's giving another error saying 'TypeError : mainWindow.loadUrl is not a function'

Comment: That's (probably) because `loadUrl()` was renamed to `loadURL()`

Comment: @CliffBurton It worked now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://electron.atom.io/blog/2015/11/17/electron-api-changes:

> Built-in modules are now grouped into one module, instead of being separated into independent modules, so you can use them without conflicts with other modules:
>
> ```
> var app = require('electron').app
> var BrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow
> ```

Also `loadUrl()` was renamed to `loadURL()`